# Use of -g and -o options in gcc command in c programming

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Suppose there are 2 c program named abc.c and xyz.c . Now we want to work with the 2 executables at a time. So we change the name of the ./a.out  using

```
gcc -g abc.c -o abc
gcc -g xyz.c -o xyz
```

Even `gcc -o abc abc.c` works.
What does the `-g` and `-o` in the above commands specify or describe?
What is the significance of `-g` and `-o` in the command for renaming ./a.out file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gcc --help` would tell you... or `man gcc`. while we're happy to help, we're not here to help you be lazy or be a replacement for checking documentation FIRST.

Comment: I tried but it did not specify in detail. It stated they are automatically passed on to various sub processes.

Comment: `gcc --help` is pretty unhelpful.  It's so focused on treating gcc as a driver for a "compiler collection" where each compiler is composed of several sub-elements, rather than giving common C/C++ compiler options aimed at new users.  It's not factually incorrect but it's aimed at the wrong level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-g` means to leave debugging information in the output file, it's unrelated to renaming.

`-o` means to put the result in the specified file instead of the default filename (`abc.o` for object files, `a.out` for linked executable files).

Comment: Thanks I understood why they are used now.

Answer (score 1):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html:

```
-g
    Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF). GDB can work with this debugging information.
```

```
-o file
    Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I understood how it is used

Answer (score 0):

-g starts becoming useful once you use debuggers such as gdb and lldb. When you attach to a running program and advancing one line at a time printing/altering the state as it changes.

Answer (score 0):

if we specify -g option while compiling, debugging symbols will be available in the output file which will be useful when you try to debug using GDB.

If we won't specify -o option, the output will be placed in default a.out file. So if we run

```
gcc a.c - output will be in a.out
gcc b.c - output is a.out which is replacing old a.out file
```

If you want the output not to be a.out file, you can give -o option while compiling

```
gcc abc.c -o a
```

-o and -g options are not related.